# render frames stuck at single frame but frame no. goes on

Tags: rendering, animation, image

I decided to render an animation and when I put it on render after 2-3 frames 
Cycles stuck on rendering single frame every time and just no. keep on increasing.

Cycles keeps rendering the same image over and over again rather than following the animation.

I'm using

- Blender 2.8
- i7 8750H
- 1050 TI 4GB

Answer (score 0):

Could be bugs. I experience that when using SkyTexture for the environment, it just sticks on rendering frame 1. Changing environment to an other background like HDRI solved my problem.

[image]

Comment: I'm having the same exact issue. Could you please explain in detail what you did to resolve it?

Comment: just go to scene tab, then change color to other options. right now im using blender 2.83 , i tried this and its not happening anymore

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, first time it got stuck at the image of frame 14, second time at the image of frame 40. Then I noticed that it always gets stuck at the last image that was played in the editor. Playing the animation till the end in the editor, then saving and then rendering works for me.